# MSBuild <Copy> Task cannot copy to the destination folder

Tags: c#, msbuild

I'm first time to use MSbuild Task and have not find the same problem. I changed .csproj file and now the problem is SourceFiles can not copy to DestinationFolder(".\IntentionSystem\Logic\Commands\xxx"),but to the path of .csproj file(".\xxx"). So what can I do to copy to DestinationFolder？

````
```<ItemGroup>
   <Compile Include="..\..\Unity\Assets\Scripts\CS_Share\Commands\*.cs" />
 </ItemGroup>

 <Target Name="CopyFiles">
   <Copy SourceFiles="@(Compile)" DestinationFolder=".\IntentionSystem\Logic\Commands\%(RecursiveDir)"/>
 </Target>```
````

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You specified in your `ItemGroup` just *.cs, which means get all files **only** in that directory. Meaning don't get files in subdirectories.

But in your DestinationFolder in the copy target, you specified to copy it to a subdirectory using metadata that does not exist: `%(RecursiveDir)`.

Now if you had specified: `Include="..\..\Unity\Assets\Scripts\CS_Share\Commands\**\*.cs"` it may have made sense.

Docs are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-select-the-files-to-build?view=vs-2019